# Hide address bar in Edge

Tags: office365, ms-office, microsoft-edge

I have tried the Edge app mode option, kiosk mode as well as the full-screen option of GPO but it does not solve my problem

My question is: Can I hide the address bar only for specific URLs but not all
and for those URLs, if I tried to open them from email or link it must not show the address bar

Can it be Possible
please someone tell me

I have heard edge control option of Microsoft also does that solve my problem?

I want to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you cannot hide the address bar in **normal mode**, particularly when you want to apply it to opening links from the email or something, because it is out of security concerns.

You can hide the address bar only if

1. You **installed the URL as an app**. For example, if I go to google.com and install it as an app, [image]
   and if you receive an email containing the google.com link, you can right click on it and select the **Open link in Google** ("Google" is the customized name you choose for the app) option. Then the link will be opened in app mode with no address bar. I think this one is the **closest solution**.

[image]

2. You open it in **fullscreen**.